# How to display iframe dashlet for all user in sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have created iframe **Dashlet** and now I want that all users should able to see it. How can I set its visibility to all users?

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the user preferences to all the users. You will need to create a script.

Comment: How to create a script?..Please elaborate it.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new default dashlet you should edit _PATH_TO_YOUR_SUGAR_/custom/modules/Home/dashlets.php and add your new dashlet in the $defaultDashlets variable like this:

```
$defaultDashlets = array(
                    'MyCallsDashlet'=>'Calls',
                    'MyMeetingsDashlet'=>'Meetings',
                    'MyOpportunitiesDashlet'=>'Opportunities',
                    'MyAccountsDashlet'=>'Accounts',
                    'MyLeadsDashlet'=>'Leads',
                    'MyCustomDashletName' => 'Custom Dashlet Name'
                     );
```

Please take in consideration, that it will be default for all NEW users, that register in the system. In case you want to add it to existing user Home dashboards you should refresh/reset their Home dashboard via Admin -> User Management -> -select user- -> Edit _> Reset Homepage ( See image )
[image]